# An example of a proof in sequent calculus

Tags: logic

I'm reading Gaisi Takeuti, *Proof Theory* (2nd ed - 1987), and I'm trying with some exercises.

See pag.13 : **Ex.2.5.2)** Prove the following in **LK** : $(A \supset B) \supset \lnot A  \lor B$.

*In order to be not too pedantic, I've omitted applications (if any) of Contraction and Exchange*.

Starting from :

$$\frac{A \rightarrow A}{\rightarrow A, \lnot A}$$ with ($\lnot$-right)

and

$${B \to B}$$

using ($\supset$-left) followed by ($\lor$-right) :

$$\frac{A \supset B \rightarrow \lnot A , B}{A \supset B \rightarrow \lnot A \lor B , B}$$

But now, how can I get rid of $B$ in the *succedent*?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake with the statement of the Exercise. I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Just turn $B$ into another $\lnot A \lor B$, then do a contraction.